# navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition didn't run sequentialy

Tags: javascript, firefox, navigator

I am trying to get geolocation data and render it by Ajax into the Dom element, but it did not behave properly with getting the data, so I tried to debug, then I found out a weird execution.

```
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos){
      console.log(1);
    });
  }
  console.log(2);
```

in the console, it showed 2 first then 1, and why is that plz? Am I missing some configs in the browser? I am using Firefox Developer Edition the newest version. I was thinking that there may be not a "navigator" object at first, but it should not show 1 at all, cause the code won't execute, I am really lost here from last night, thanks for any help.

Comment: `getCurrentPosition()` is __Asynchronous__ thus behavior is expected.

Comment: Thank you, so is that where we need a callback before and now we use promise in ES6?